# How to use Powershell to get all users profiles and assign a value

Tags: powershell, profile

I have the following Command and it gets the username:

```
((Get-WMIObject -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).Username).Split('\')[1]
```

The trouble I am having is figuring out how to have a letter (Value) assigned to each profile

Example:

```
User1
User2
User3 

User1=%A%
User2=%B%
User3=%C%
```

so I can use the variables in a later part of the script.

I have tried adding code, looking up similar commands and scripts with no luck.

Can someone please tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: You're looking to associate each username with a custom value? How would you decide which value to associated with which username?

Comment: In addition to the top comment, you want to query the `win32_userprofile` class for all profiles and not the one logged into the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some different ways to solve this.

### The powershell way:

```
$admin=get-credential -Message "Admin credentials"
$paths=Get-WMIObject -ClassName Win32_UserProfile -Filter "special=false and localpath like 'C:\\users\\%'" -Property localpath |select -ExpandProperty localpath
$destination="\\server\d$\desktopbackups"
foreach ($source in $paths) {
    $user = Split-Path -Path $source -leaf
    $sourceDesktop = join-path $source "Desktop"
    $DestFolder = Join-Path $destination $user
    write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Backing up $sourceDesktop to folder $destfolder"
    
    # First delete the destination
    remove-item $destfolder -Filter *.* -Recurse -Credential $admin -WhatIf

    # Copy the files
    Copy-Item $sourceDesktop $DestFolder -Recurse -Credential $admin -WhatIf
}
```

The above solution allows you to enter the admin credentials and the file operations are done as your admin user. You don't have to log in as a different user to use this.

### The output-cmdscript way:

```
$paths=Get-WMIObject -ClassName Win32_UserProfile -Filter "special=false and localpath like 'C:\\users\\%'" -Property localpath |select -ExpandProperty localpath
$destination="\\server\d$\desktopbackups"
$cmdscriptfile="c:\temp\backupDesktops.cmd"
foreach ($source in $paths) {
    $user = Split-Path -Path $source -leaf
    $srcfolder = join-path $source "Desktop"
    $DestFolder = Join-Path $destination $user
    "xcopy $srcfolder $Destfolder" | out-file -Append $cmdscriptfile
}
```

The above script creates a cmd-script which you can log in as admin and run.

### The output-cmdscript-variables way:

```
$paths=Get-WMIObject -ClassName Win32_UserProfile -Filter "special=false and localpath like 'C:\\users\\%'" -Property localpath |select -ExpandProperty localpath
$cmdscriptfile="c:\temp\backupDesktops.cmd"
Clear-Content $cmdscriptfile
$i=65
foreach ($source in $paths) {
    $user = Split-Path -Path $source -leaf
    "set {0}={1}" -f [char]$i,$user | out-file -Append $cmdscriptfile
    $i++
}
"xcopy c:\users\%A%\Desktops ..."|Out-File -Append $cmdscriptfile
```

The above lets you edit the cmd file and use the different variables for the paths. This is what you asked for (if I understood correctly).

Personally I would use Powershell.

Comment: I have a script that backs up a users profile. I would like to be able to display the profiles so I can choose which I back up. Like Jsmith, Djones, Measy.... So if I want to choose DJones, the value is %B%.

Comment: Does the above script solve that problem or do you want me to change something?

Comment: I may have described it incorrectly. I would like the User to be assigned a variable so I can add it to the script. Example: Xcopy c:\User\%A%\Desktop to transfer the correct user. This way I can run it from my admin account and not be logged in as the user....

Comment: If the answer answers your question, please mark it as an answer. Otherwise we could change something.

Comment: What I am looking for is comparable to what a Batch script does. Set MJONES=A KSMITH=B   And if I echo %A% %B% it echoes MJONES and KSMITH so I can use the Variables throughout my script. Something comparable to this, but assigns a variable   Echo off
For /D %%G In ("C:\Users\*") Do @Echo %%~nxG
pause

Comment: Then use the last solution (output-cmdscript-variables). Run the script, open c:\temp\backupDesktops.cmd and edit as you wish. The Set command in your last comment has to be Set A=MJONES. You have the order wrong.